# Why are the techniques of kriya yoga a secret while it is mentioned in Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, kriyayoga

There is an air of secrecy around kriya yoga and its practice. While all teachers/gurus tell that kriya yoga is clearly outlined in the Gita - then what is the point of secrecy ?

Comment: Kriya is outlined Gita offering Prana to Apana and Apana to Prana but the method to do that is secret because this is Guru-disciple Diksha... Everything has its own Dharma, process,

Comment: Techniques of Kriya are not secret. It is imparted

Comment: clearly outlined?? No one practices Kriya Yoga by seeing texts like BG. It is a philosophical text and not a practitioner's guideline. And even in general, advanced Yoga techniques are to be learned only from the Guru.. Scriptures intentionally will give vague descriptions.

Comment: It is not that they are secret, they are sacred. They are imparted to a person when they are ready to receive them.